# Equivalent of Php __invoke() in other langages

Tags: php, oop, callable

Is there any other Object Oriented language where there is a concept equivalent to Php `__invoke` method, which allows an object to be treated as a function/callable?

Comment: [First class function # Language support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function#Language_support)

Comment: @Timurib having first class function is different than having invokable/callable objects

Comment: Yes, but it depends on what "object" means. Closure may be considered as invocable object (["Closures And Objects Are Equivalent"](http://wiki.c2.com/?ClosuresAndObjectsAreEquivalent)). Btw, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object

Answer (score 2):

You want languages that allow [operator overloading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading#Catalog), since that's what the PHP [`__invoke`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) is designed to be similar to.

For example, in C++ you could do the following:

```
#include <iostream>

class Test
{
    public:
        Test() : m_i(42) {}

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Test& t)
        {
            os << t.m_i;
            return os;
        }

        operator int()
        {
            return this->m_i;
        }

        void operator()()
        {
            std::cout << *this << std::endl;
        }

    private:
        int m_i;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Test t;
    // calls the operator<< overload to print "t"
    std::cout << "t = " << t << std::endl;
    // calls the void operator()() to treat "t" as a function
    t();
    // calls the operator int() to treat "t" as an int type
    int i = t;
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And in C# you could do something like the following:

```
class Test
{
    private int m_i = 42;
    public delegate void MyDelegate(params int[] parms);

    public static implicit operator int(Test t)
    {
        return t.m_i;
    }

    public static implicit operator MyDelegate(Test t)
    {
        return t.Invoke;
    }

    private void Invoke(params int[] parms)
    {
        foreach (int i in parms) {
            this.m_i += i;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}", this.m_i);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.m_i.ToString();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Test t = new Test();
    // calls t.ToString()
    Console.WriteLine("t = {0}", t);
    int d = t; // implicit cast to int
    Delegate g = t; // implicit cast to Delegate type
    Console.WriteLine("d = {0}", d);
    // invoke the method pointed to by the delegate
    g.DynamicInvoke(new int[] { 10, 20, 30 });
    d = t; // implicit cast
    Console.WriteLine("d = {0}", d);
}
```

To this though, while operator overloading can be handy, as with any language functionality, you might want to think about *why* you're overloading the operator and if another more reader-friendly OOP idiom might not suffice that could also traverse multiple languages.

For example, in all of these examples, and in PHP, you could write a simple function overload that does what you need and would be easily readable across multiple languages:

### PHP

```
class Test {
    $m_i;

    function Invoke() { return $m_i; }
    function Invoke($x) { return $m_i + $x; }
}
```

### C++

```
class Test {
    private: int m_i;
    public:
        int Invoke() { return this->m_i; }
        int Invoke(int x) { return this->m_i + x; }
};
```

### C#

```
class Test {
    private int m_i;
    public int Invoke() { return this.m_i; }
    public int Invoke(int x) { return this.m_i + x; }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: thanks, operator overloading is just a way to obtain invokable objects. For example in Php you can not override operators, but you have invokable objects baked in by default

Comment: @marcosh .. yup, and in PHP you can also treat a `string` as an `int`, which in other languages causes a compile error; going from a dynamic language like PHP to a static language presents other issues that need to be thought of. Lua is very similar to PHP in that regards though and pretty popular; so you might want to check out Lua for those kinds of similarities in language.